# Foreman 404 while trying to obtain the token

Tags: foreman, spacewalk

Foreman is giving my kickstart hosts a 404 while trying to get the token. Any ideas what this could be caused by? I tried with wget as well but no luck.
/var/log/http/foreman_access.log:

```
-0400] "GET /unattended/provision?token=8cc70a17-f408-4907-bf5c-82d7224dbb49 HTTP/1.1" 404 100 "-" "anaconda/13.21.229"
1.1.1.48 - - [27/Aug/2015:20:00:59 -0400] "GET /unattended/provision?token=8cc70a17-f408-4907-bf5c-82d7224dbb49 HTTP/1.1" 404 100 "-" "anaconda/13.21.229"
1.1.1.48 - - [27/Aug/2015:20:01:05 -0400] "GET /unattended/provision?token=8cc70a17-f408-4907-bf5c-82d7224dbb49 HTTP/1.1" 404 100 "-" "anaconda/13.21.229"
1.1.1.48 - - [27/Aug/2015:20:01:33 -0400] "GET /unattended/provision?token=8cc70a17-f408-4907-bf5c-82d7224dbb49 HTTP/1.1" 404 100 "-" "anaconda/13.21.229"
::1 - - [27/Aug/2015:20:02:37 -0400] "GET /unattended/provision?token=8cc70a17-f408-4907-bf5c-82d7224dbb49 HTTP/1.0" 404 100 "-" "Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)"
10.12.17.189 - - [27/Aug/2015:20:03:06 -0400] "GET /unattended/provision?token=8cc70a17-f408-4907-bf5c-82d7224dbb49 HTTP/1.0" 404 100 "-" "Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)"
1.1.1.53 - - [27/Aug/2015:20:08:03 -0400] "GET /unattended/provision?token=8919c018-2bad-4177-a04e-b4759af9980b HTTP/1.1" 404 100 "-" "anaconda/13.21.229"
1.1.1.53 - - [27/Aug/2015:20:09:45 -0400] "GET /unattended/provision?token=8919c018-2bad-4177-a04e-b4759af9980b HTTP/1.1" 404 100 "-" "anaconda/13.21.229"
1.1.1.53 - - [27/Aug/2015:20:09:54 -0400] "GET /unattended/provision?token=8919c018-2bad-4177-a04e-b4759af9980b HTTP/1.1" 404 100 "-" "anaconda/13.21.229"
```

Comment: Can you include Foreman's log file?  /var/log/foreman/production.log